# Error while rendering HTML template using Thymeleaf 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor'

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm having trouble rendering a HTML page using Thymeleaf and Spring Boot. I get an error while it's trying to tag the fields in the html file to the ones in the class.

The error is: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "userPreview" - line 10, col 32)

HTML template:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Email User Preview</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Send E-mail:</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/sendmail}" th:object="${message}" method="post">
    <p>To:: <input type="text" th:field="*{receiverEmail}" /></p>
    <p>Subject: <input type="text" th:field="*{subject}" /></p>
    <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{message}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String send() {
        user.setEmailAddress("yasseen.salama@gmail.com");
        try {
            emailService.sendMail(user, "Hello", "Test");

        } catch (MailException mailException) {
            System.out.println(mailException);
        }
        return "Email sent.";
    }
    @GetMapping("/sendmail")
    public String sendingMail(Model model) {
        Message message = new Message();
        model.addAttribute("userPreview", message);
        return "userPreview";
    }

    @PostMapping("/sendmail")
    public String mailSubmit(@ModelAttribute Message message) {
        return "Result";
    }
}
```

class Message:

```
public class Message {
    String receiverEmail;
    String subject;
    String message;

    public String getReceiverEmail() {
        return receiverEmail;
    }

    public void setReceiverEmail(String receiverEmail) {
        this.receiverEmail = receiverEmail;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object or the variable name to be used in template is `userPreview` and not `message` because that's the key in your Model object